# Visualforce Page with Standard controller not updating parent record

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, inputfield

I have a relatively simple VF page that is launched from a button on a custom object called 'Inclusion_detail__c. The page uses the standard Controller and is effectively a data entry form for specific fields which works perfectly from fields on the Inclusion_detail__c object. I want to extend this to add a field from the parent Contact record which is a master-detail relationship. The field renders perfectly, but when I press Save, the parent fields do not update. Can this be achieved with a standard controller or do I need an extension? Do I need to pass in the Contact parameter somewhere?

```
<apex:page standardController="Inclusion_Details__c">
<apex:pageMessages />
<h1 style="font-size:200%;"><font color="#0000ff" text-align="center"><b>Hello {!$User.FirstName}</b></font></h1> Please enter the MASI infromation for <b> {!Inclusion_Details__c.Contact__r.Name} </b><br></br><br></br>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Enter MASI">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>                
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>


        <apex:pageblockSection title="Consent" >
            <apex:inputfield value="{!Inclusion_Details__c.Contact__r.Agree_to_main_consent_statement__c}"/>          
            <apex:inputfield value="{!Inclusion_Details__c.Contact__r.Team__c}"/>          
        </apex:pageblockSection>


        <apex:pageblockSection title="Legal Guardian" > 
            <apex:inputText value="{!Inclusion_Details__c.Are_you_the_legal_guardian__c}"/>            
            <apex:inputField value="{!Inclusion_Details__c.Name_of_legal_guardian__c}"/>            
            <apex:inputField value="{!Inclusion_Details__c.Address_of_legal_guardian__c}"/>            
            <apex:inputField value="{!Inclusion_Details__c.Legal_guardian_call_back_time__c}"/>            
            <apex:inputField value="{!Inclusion_Details__c.Further_info_on_legal_guardian__c}"/>            
            <apex:inputField value="{!Inclusion_Details__c.Legal_Guardian_Telephone__c}"/>            
        </apex:pageblockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you want to update `Contact` record using update action on the `Inclusion_Details__c` sobject. Standard Controller can't actually know about related Parent (Contact). So, you need to create an Extension for this controller and override `save` method where you can update contact separately like so:

```
Contact con = Inclusion_Details__r.Contact__r;
update con;
```

or you can add Inclusion_Details__c and Contact records to generic List - `List<SObject>` and update them in the one DML statement:

```
List<SObject> recordsToUpadte = new List<SObject>{
   inclusion,
   con
}
update recordsToUpdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a controller extension to update the record. It cannot be achieved through StandardController as per my understanding.